# Facebook Graph API publish comments with attachment_id

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-comments

I'm trying to post a comment with an attached image instead of a message using Facebook graph API.

According to the docs it is posible to publish a comment with an optional id of 
a unpublished photo but after hours of testing I haven't manage to make it work.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/object/comments/

Also debugging with the Graph API Exploerer I always get the same error:"An unknown error,"OAuthException".

Can anyone show an example of how to use the attachment_id to post a comment?, maybe I'm missing something that is not mentioned in the docs.

Thanks

Comment: [Update] The attachment_id parameter for the comments has a bug. I have submitted the issue to Facebook and they have accepted as a bug:

https://developers.facebook.com/x/bugs/745764125435154/

Comment: They have closed that bug, created new one: https://developers.facebook.com/x/bugs/406219529521415/
Let's vote and subscribe!